# What can be the maximum number of entries in boost bimap

Tags: c++, boost-bimap

I am trying to create a `boost bimap` of total 177 million entries.I created a `boost bimap`

```
namespace bimaps = boost::bimaps;
typedef boost::bimap<bimaps::unordered_set_of<unsigned long long int>,
        bimaps::unordered_multiset_of<unsigned long long int> > bimap_reference;
typedef bimap_reference::value_type position;
bimap_reference reference_index_vector;
```

and entered the elements but it stopped entering the elements when reaching 100 million, 66 thousand entries. I would like to know if there is any maximum limit of `boost bimap`, or there can be some other problem.

Comment: "It stopped"? With what? My guess would be `std::bad_alloc`, meaning "I ran out of memory"

Comment: @dhke It did not give any message like `std::bad_alloc`. I display message on every entry and the program just got still. I work on 16 GB RAM

Comment: Is the program compiled for 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @zett42 its for 64

Comment: Can you please verify this by printing the result of `sizeof(void*)`?

Comment: @zett42 It displays 8

Comment: @AwaitedOne Look at the memory consumption of your program before it "stops entering elements" - If it reaches ~16 GB, it means that you do not have enough memory to store all your entries, it it reaches ~4 GB, it might mean that you compiled a 32-bits executable.

Comment: @Holt Thank you, I'll check that.